# HTTP error 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: http

When I click on the link it gives 403 error, it is working fine on local environment. This is the line where error occurs:

```
$.post('./../../wp-content/plugins/test/app/controller/summary.php', data,  function(response) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You first need to confirm if you have encountered a "No directory browsing" problem. You can see this if the URL ends in a slash '/' rather than the name of a specific Web page (e.g. .htm or .html). If this is your problem, then you have no option but to access individual Web pages for that Web site directly.

Comment: Yes URL ends in a slash

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any substatus? This error code means your browser is not allowed to access this ressource. That means the resource is there but not vissible for you.

Comment: This is the only error                                                                               POST  (URL) 403 (Forbidden)